# Picking a value from several alternative columns into a new one

Tags: r

Let's say I have this kind of dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
             number = c("9", "4", "3", "10", "5"),
             variable1 = c("80", "43", "2", "91", "22"),
             variable3 = c("65", "71", "100", "98", "13"),
             variable6 = c("72", "56", "90", "25", "34"),
             variable9 = c("99", "1", "68", "39", "66"))
```

I want to summarise my variables into one "real_variable" in a way that the "number" defines which value is picked into the new variable. The value should be picked from a column which (1) has a number (in the column name) smaller than the "number" AND (2) has the highest number available (in the column name). The final output should look like this:

```
 id number real_variable
  1      9            72
  2      4            71
  3      2             2
  4     10            39
  5      5            13
```

Thanks for advice!

Comment: Start by pivoting to long-form data, and it becomes much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## pivot, filter

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, number)) |>
  mutate(num2 = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", name))) |>
  filter(num2 < number) |>
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = num2, by = id) |>
  select(id, real_variable = value) |>
  right_join(df, by = "id")
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   id    real_variable number variable1 variable3 variable6 variable9
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 1     72            9      80        65        72        99       
# 2 2     71            4      43        71        56        1        
# 3 3     2             3      2         100       90        68       
# 4 4     91            10     91        98        25        39       
# 5 5     13            5      22        13        34        66
```

### EDIT

As @Ben pointed out, we have a flaw in the 4th row, where comparing strings performs differently than comparing integers.

For demonstration:

```r
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, number)) |>
  mutate(num2 = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", name))) |>
  filter(num2 < number, id == 4)
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
#   id    number name      value  num2
#   <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <int>
# 1 4     10     variable1 91        1
df |>
  mutate(across(-id, as.integer)) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, number)) |>
  mutate(num2 = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", name))) |>
  filter(num2 < number, id == 4)
# # A tibble: 4 × 5
#   id    number name      value  num2
#   <chr>  <int> <chr>     <int> <int>
# 1 4         10 variable1    91     1
# 2 4         10 variable3    98     3
# 3 4         10 variable6    25     6
# 4 4         10 variable9    39     9
```

You can either change all number-like things (other than `id`) to integers *up front*:

```r
df |>
  mutate(across(-id, as.integer)) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, number)) |>
  mutate(num2 = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", name))) |>
  filter(num2 < number) |>
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = num2, by = id) |>
  select(id, real_variable = value) |>
  right_join(df, by = "id")
```

or just compare against an integerized `number`:

```r
df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(id, number)) |>
  mutate(num2 = as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", name))) |>
  filter(num2 < as.integer(number)) |>
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = num2, by = id) |>
  select(id, real_variable = value) |>
  right_join(df, by = "id")
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   id    real_variable number variable1 variable3 variable6 variable9
#   <chr> <chr>         <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 1     72            9      80        65        72        99       
# 2 2     71            4      43        71        56        1        
# 3 3     2             3      2         100       90        68       
# 4 4     39            10     91        98        25        39       
# 5 5     13            5      22        13        34        66
```

Both give the same output, with `id==4` having a new value of `39`.